# Как сделать вот такую классную фишку как на Facebook

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Здравствуйте! Зашел на Facebook в консоль и увидел такое:
[image: Консоль на Faceebok]

Как мне сделать такое же?

Comment: А в Firefox еще и картинку из текста показывает :)  А что, посетители часто консоль смотрят?

Comment: @labris Нет, просто тема прикольная.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё просто: сообщения в консоль можно форматировать и применять к ним *CSS*

```js
console.log('%c Остановитесь! ', 'background: blue; color: red; text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black; font-size: 50px;');
```

**Замечание:** следует открыть консоль браузера, ибо песочница не покажет как надо

`%c` — оформляет вывод с соответствии с CSS, переданным дополнительным параметром.

---

#### Дополнение:

помимо вывода на основе CSS можно по другому форматировать вывод в консоль. О других параметрах можно посмотреть **[в соседнем ответе от @Elena](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656353/191482)**

---

Нашел на enSO весёлую штуку, которую можно сотворить:

```js
var css = "text-shadow: -1px -1px hsl(0,100%,50%), 1px 1px hsl(5.4, 100%, 50%), 3px 2px hsl(10.8, 100%, 50%), 5px 3px hsl(16.2, 100%, 50%), 7px 4px hsl(21.6, 100%, 50%), 9px 5px hsl(27, 100%, 50%), 11px 6px hsl(32.4, 100%, 50%), 13px 7px hsl(37.8, 100%, 50%), 14px 8px hsl(43.2, 100%, 50%), 16px 9px hsl(48.6, 100%, 50%), 18px 10px hsl(54, 100%, 50%), 20px 11px hsl(59.4, 100%, 50%), 22px 12px hsl(64.8, 100%, 50%), 23px 13px hsl(70.2, 100%, 50%), 25px 14px hsl(75.6, 100%, 50%), 27px 15px hsl(81, 100%, 50%), 28px 16px hsl(86.4, 100%, 50%), 30px 17px hsl(91.8, 100%, 50%), 32px 18px hsl(97.2, 100%, 50%), 33px 19px hsl(102.6, 100%, 50%), 35px 20px hsl(108, 100%, 50%), 36px 21px hsl(113.4, 100%, 50%), 38px 22px hsl(118.8, 100%, 50%), 39px 23px hsl(124.2, 100%, 50%), 41px 24px hsl(129.6, 100%, 50%), 42px 25px hsl(135, 100%, 50%), 43px 26px hsl(140.4, 100%, 50%), 45px 27px hsl(145.8, 100%, 50%), 46px 28px hsl(151.2, 100%, 50%), 47px 29px hsl(156.6, 100%, 50%), 48px 30px hsl(162, 100%, 50%), 49px 31px hsl(167.4, 100%, 50%), 50px 32px hsl(172.8, 100%, 50%), 51px 33px hsl(178.2, 100%, 50%), 52px 34px hsl(183.6, 100%, 50%), 53px 35px hsl(189, 100%, 50%), 54px 36px hsl(194.4, 100%, 50%), 55px 37px hsl(199.8, 100%, 50%), 55px 38px hsl(205.2, 100%, 50%), 56px 39px hsl(210.6, 100%, 50%), 57px 40px hsl(216, 100%, 50%), 57px 41px hsl(221.4, 100%, 50%), 58px 42px hsl(226.8, 100%, 50%), 58px 43px hsl(232.2, 100%, 50%), 58px 44px hsl(237.6, 100%, 50%), 59px 45px hsl(243, 100%, 50%), 59px 46px hsl(248.4, 100%, 50%), 59px 47px hsl(253.8, 100%, 50%), 59px 48px hsl(259.2, 100%, 50%), 59px 49px hsl(264.6, 100%, 50%), 60px 50px hsl(270, 100%, 50%), 59px 51px hsl(275.4, 100%, 50%), 59px 52px hsl(280.8, 100%, 50%), 59px 53px hsl(286.2, 100%, 50%), 59px 54px hsl(291.6, 100%, 50%), 59px 55px hsl(297, 100%, 50%), 58px 56px hsl(302.4, 100%, 50%), 58px 57px hsl(307.8, 100%, 50%), 58px 58px hsl(313.2, 100%, 50%), 57px 59px hsl(318.6, 100%, 50%), 57px 60px hsl(324, 100%, 50%), 56px 61px hsl(329.4, 100%, 50%), 55px 62px hsl(334.8, 100%, 50%), 55px 63px hsl(340.2, 100%, 50%), 54px 64px hsl(345.6, 100%, 50%), 53px 65px hsl(351, 100%, 50%), 52px 66px hsl(356.4, 100%, 50%), 51px 67px hsl(361.8, 100%, 50%), 50px 68px hsl(367.2, 100%, 50%), 49px 69px hsl(372.6, 100%, 50%), 48px 70px hsl(378, 100%, 50%), 47px 71px hsl(383.4, 100%, 50%), 46px 72px hsl(388.8, 100%, 50%), 45px 73px hsl(394.2, 100%, 50%), 43px 74px hsl(399.6, 100%, 50%), 42px 75px hsl(405, 100%, 50%), 41px 76px hsl(410.4, 100%, 50%), 39px 77px hsl(415.8, 100%, 50%), 38px 78px hsl(421.2, 100%, 50%), 36px 79px hsl(426.6, 100%, 50%), 35px 80px hsl(432, 100%, 50%), 33px 81px hsl(437.4, 100%, 50%), 32px 82px hsl(442.8, 100%, 50%), 30px 83px hsl(448.2, 100%, 50%), 28px 84px hsl(453.6, 100%, 50%), 27px 85px hsl(459, 100%, 50%), 25px 86px hsl(464.4, 100%, 50%), 23px 87px hsl(469.8, 100%, 50%), 22px 88px hsl(475.2, 100%, 50%), 20px 89px hsl(480.6, 100%, 50%), 18px 90px hsl(486, 100%, 50%), 16px 91px hsl(491.4, 100%, 50%), 14px 92px hsl(496.8, 100%, 50%), 13px 93px hsl(502.2, 100%, 50%), 11px 94px hsl(507.6, 100%, 50%), 9px 95px hsl(513, 100%, 50%), 7px 96px hsl(518.4, 100%, 50%), 5px 97px hsl(523.8, 100%, 50%), 3px 98px hsl(529.2, 100%, 50%), 1px 99px hsl(534.6, 100%, 50%), 7px 100px hsl(540, 100%, 50%), -1px 101px hsl(545.4, 100%, 50%), -3px 102px hsl(550.8, 100%, 50%), -5px 103px hsl(556.2, 100%, 50%), -7px 104px hsl(561.6, 100%, 50%), -9px 105px hsl(567, 100%, 50%), -11px 106px hsl(572.4, 100%, 50%), -13px 107px hsl(577.8, 100%, 50%), -14px 108px hsl(583.2, 100%, 50%), -16px 109px hsl(588.6, 100%, 50%), -18px 110px hsl(594, 100%, 50%), -20px 111px hsl(599.4, 100%, 50%), -22px 112px hsl(604.8, 100%, 50%), -23px 113px hsl(610.2, 100%, 50%), -25px 114px hsl(615.6, 100%, 50%), -27px 115px hsl(621, 100%, 50%), -28px 116px hsl(626.4, 100%, 50%), -30px 117px hsl(631.8, 100%, 50%), -32px 118px hsl(637.2, 100%, 50%), -33px 119px hsl(642.6, 100%, 50%), -35px 120px hsl(648, 100%, 50%), -36px 121px hsl(653.4, 100%, 50%), -38px 122px hsl(658.8, 100%, 50%), -39px 123px hsl(664.2, 100%, 50%), -41px 124px hsl(669.6, 100%, 50%), -42px 125px hsl(675, 100%, 50%), -43px 126px hsl(680.4, 100%, 50%), -45px 127px hsl(685.8, 100%, 50%), -46px 128px hsl(691.2, 100%, 50%), -47px 129px hsl(696.6, 100%, 50%), -48px 130px hsl(702, 100%, 50%), -49px 131px hsl(707.4, 100%, 50%), -50px 132px hsl(712.8, 100%, 50%), -51px 133px hsl(718.2, 100%, 50%), -52px 134px hsl(723.6, 100%, 50%), -53px 135px hsl(729, 100%, 50%), -54px 136px hsl(734.4, 100%, 50%), -55px 137px hsl(739.8, 100%, 50%), -55px 138px hsl(745.2, 100%, 50%), -56px 139px hsl(750.6, 100%, 50%), -57px 140px hsl(756, 100%, 50%), -57px 141px hsl(761.4, 100%, 50%), -58px 142px hsl(766.8, 100%, 50%), -58px 143px hsl(772.2, 100%, 50%), -58px 144px hsl(777.6, 100%, 50%), -59px 145px hsl(783, 100%, 50%), -59px 146px hsl(788.4, 100%, 50%), -59px 147px hsl(793.8, 100%, 50%), -59px 148px hsl(799.2, 100%, 50%), -59px 149px hsl(804.6, 100%, 50%), -60px 150px hsl(810, 100%, 50%), -59px 151px hsl(815.4, 100%, 50%), -59px 152px hsl(820.8, 100%, 50%), -59px 153px hsl(826.2, 100%, 50%), -59px 154px hsl(831.6, 100%, 50%), -59px 155px hsl(837, 100%, 50%), -58px 156px hsl(842.4, 100%, 50%), -58px 157px hsl(847.8, 100%, 50%), -58px 158px hsl(853.2, 100%, 50%), -57px 159px hsl(858.6, 100%, 50%), -57px 160px hsl(864, 100%, 50%), -56px 161px hsl(869.4, 100%, 50%), -55px 162px hsl(874.8, 100%, 50%), -55px 163px hsl(880.2, 100%, 50%), -54px 164px hsl(885.6, 100%, 50%), -53px 165px hsl(891, 100%, 50%), -52px 166px hsl(896.4, 100%, 50%), -51px 167px hsl(901.8, 100%, 50%), -50px 168px hsl(907.2, 100%, 50%), -49px 169px hsl(912.6, 100%, 50%), -48px 170px hsl(918, 100%, 50%), -47px 171px hsl(923.4, 100%, 50%), -46px 172px hsl(928.8, 100%, 50%), -45px 173px hsl(934.2, 100%, 50%), -43px 174px hsl(939.6, 100%, 50%), -42px 175px hsl(945, 100%, 50%), -41px 176px hsl(950.4, 100%, 50%), -39px 177px hsl(955.8, 100%, 50%), -38px 178px hsl(961.2, 100%, 50%), -36px 179px hsl(966.6, 100%, 50%), -35px 180px hsl(972, 100%, 50%), -33px 181px hsl(977.4, 100%, 50%), -32px 182px hsl(982.8, 100%, 50%), -30px 183px hsl(988.2, 100%, 50%), -28px 184px hsl(993.6, 100%, 50%), -27px 185px hsl(999, 100%, 50%), -25px 186px hsl(1004.4, 100%, 50%), -23px 187px hsl(1009.8, 100%, 50%), -22px 188px hsl(1015.2, 100%, 50%), -20px 189px hsl(1020.6, 100%, 50%), -18px 190px hsl(1026, 100%, 50%), -16px 191px hsl(1031.4, 100%, 50%), -14px 192px hsl(1036.8, 100%, 50%), -13px 193px hsl(1042.2, 100%, 50%), -11px 194px hsl(1047.6, 100%, 50%), -9px 195px hsl(1053, 100%, 50%), -7px 196px hsl(1058.4, 100%, 50%), -5px 197px hsl(1063.8, 100%, 50%), -3px 198px hsl(1069.2, 100%, 50%), -1px 199px hsl(1074.6, 100%, 50%), -1px 200px hsl(1080, 100%, 50%), 1px 201px hsl(1085.4, 100%, 50%), 3px 202px hsl(1090.8, 100%, 50%), 5px 203px hsl(1096.2, 100%, 50%), 7px 204px hsl(1101.6, 100%, 50%), 9px 205px hsl(1107, 100%, 50%), 11px 206px hsl(1112.4, 100%, 50%), 13px 207px hsl(1117.8, 100%, 50%), 14px 208px hsl(1123.2, 100%, 50%), 16px 209px hsl(1128.6, 100%, 50%), 18px 210px hsl(1134, 100%, 50%), 20px 211px hsl(1139.4, 100%, 50%), 22px 212px hsl(1144.8, 100%, 50%), 23px 213px hsl(1150.2, 100%, 50%), 25px 214px hsl(1155.6, 100%, 50%), 27px 215px hsl(1161, 100%, 50%), 28px 216px hsl(1166.4, 100%, 50%), 30px 217px hsl(1171.8, 100%, 50%), 32px 218px hsl(1177.2, 100%, 50%), 33px 219px hsl(1182.6, 100%, 50%), 35px 220px hsl(1188, 100%, 50%), 36px 221px hsl(1193.4, 100%, 50%), 38px 222px hsl(1198.8, 100%, 50%), 39px 223px hsl(1204.2, 100%, 50%), 41px 224px hsl(1209.6, 100%, 50%), 42px 225px hsl(1215, 100%, 50%), 43px 226px hsl(1220.4, 100%, 50%), 45px 227px hsl(1225.8, 100%, 50%), 46px 228px hsl(1231.2, 100%, 50%), 47px 229px hsl(1236.6, 100%, 50%), 48px 230px hsl(1242, 100%, 50%), 49px 231px hsl(1247.4, 100%, 50%), 50px 232px hsl(1252.8, 100%, 50%), 51px 233px hsl(1258.2, 100%, 50%), 52px 234px hsl(1263.6, 100%, 50%), 53px 235px hsl(1269, 100%, 50%), 54px 236px hsl(1274.4, 100%, 50%), 55px 237px hsl(1279.8, 100%, 50%), 55px 238px hsl(1285.2, 100%, 50%), 56px 239px hsl(1290.6, 100%, 50%), 57px 240px hsl(1296, 100%, 50%), 57px 241px hsl(1301.4, 100%, 50%), 58px 242px hsl(1306.8, 100%, 50%), 58px 243px hsl(1312.2, 100%, 50%), 58px 244px hsl(1317.6, 100%, 50%), 59px 245px hsl(1323, 100%, 50%), 59px 246px hsl(1328.4, 100%, 50%), 59px 247px hsl(1333.8, 100%, 50%), 59px 248px hsl(1339.2, 100%, 50%), 59px 249px hsl(1344.6, 100%, 50%), 60px 250px hsl(1350, 100%, 50%), 59px 251px hsl(1355.4, 100%, 50%), 59px 252px hsl(1360.8, 100%, 50%), 59px 253px hsl(1366.2, 100%, 50%), 59px 254px hsl(1371.6, 100%, 50%), 59px 255px hsl(1377, 100%, 50%), 58px 256px hsl(1382.4, 100%, 50%), 58px 257px hsl(1387.8, 100%, 50%), 58px 258px hsl(1393.2, 100%, 50%), 57px 259px hsl(1398.6, 100%, 50%), 57px 260px hsl(1404, 100%, 50%), 56px 261px hsl(1409.4, 100%, 50%), 55px 262px hsl(1414.8, 100%, 50%), 55px 263px hsl(1420.2, 100%, 50%), 54px 264px hsl(1425.6, 100%, 50%), 53px 265px hsl(1431, 100%, 50%), 52px 266px hsl(1436.4, 100%, 50%), 51px 267px hsl(1441.8, 100%, 50%), 50px 268px hsl(1447.2, 100%, 50%), 49px 269px hsl(1452.6, 100%, 50%), 48px 270px hsl(1458, 100%, 50%), 47px 271px hsl(1463.4, 100%, 50%), 46px 272px hsl(1468.8, 100%, 50%), 45px 273px hsl(1474.2, 100%, 50%), 43px 274px hsl(1479.6, 100%, 50%), 42px 275px hsl(1485, 100%, 50%), 41px 276px hsl(1490.4, 100%, 50%), 39px 277px hsl(1495.8, 100%, 50%), 38px 278px hsl(1501.2, 100%, 50%), 36px 279px hsl(1506.6, 100%, 50%), 35px 280px hsl(1512, 100%, 50%), 33px 281px hsl(1517.4, 100%, 50%), 32px 282px hsl(1522.8, 100%, 50%), 30px 283px hsl(1528.2, 100%, 50%), 28px 284px hsl(1533.6, 100%, 50%), 27px 285px hsl(1539, 100%, 50%), 25px 286px hsl(1544.4, 100%, 50%), 23px 287px hsl(1549.8, 100%, 50%), 22px 288px hsl(1555.2, 100%, 50%), 20px 289px hsl(1560.6, 100%, 50%), 18px 290px hsl(1566, 100%, 50%), 16px 291px hsl(1571.4, 100%, 50%), 14px 292px hsl(1576.8, 100%, 50%), 13px 293px hsl(1582.2, 100%, 50%), 11px 294px hsl(1587.6, 100%, 50%), 9px 295px hsl(1593, 100%, 50%), 7px 296px hsl(1598.4, 100%, 50%), 5px 297px hsl(1603.8, 100%, 50%), 3px 298px hsl(1609.2, 100%, 50%), 1px 299px hsl(1614.6, 100%, 50%), 2px 300px hsl(1620, 100%, 50%), -1px 301px hsl(1625.4, 100%, 50%), -3px 302px hsl(1630.8, 100%, 50%), -5px 303px hsl(1636.2, 100%, 50%), -7px 304px hsl(1641.6, 100%, 50%), -9px 305px hsl(1647, 100%, 50%), -11px 306px hsl(1652.4, 100%, 50%), -13px 307px hsl(1657.8, 100%, 50%), -14px 308px hsl(1663.2, 100%, 50%), -16px 309px hsl(1668.6, 100%, 50%), -18px 310px hsl(1674, 100%, 50%), -20px 311px hsl(1679.4, 100%, 50%), -22px 312px hsl(1684.8, 100%, 50%), -23px 313px hsl(1690.2, 100%, 50%), -25px 314px hsl(1695.6, 100%, 50%), -27px 315px hsl(1701, 100%, 50%), -28px 316px hsl(1706.4, 100%, 50%), -30px 317px hsl(1711.8, 100%, 50%), -32px 318px hsl(1717.2, 100%, 50%), -33px 319px hsl(1722.6, 100%, 50%), -35px 320px hsl(1728, 100%, 50%), -36px 321px hsl(1733.4, 100%, 50%), -38px 322px hsl(1738.8, 100%, 50%), -39px 323px hsl(1744.2, 100%, 50%), -41px 324px hsl(1749.6, 100%, 50%), -42px 325px hsl(1755, 100%, 50%), -43px 326px hsl(1760.4, 100%, 50%), -45px 327px hsl(1765.8, 100%, 50%), -46px 328px hsl(1771.2, 100%, 50%), -47px 329px hsl(1776.6, 100%, 50%), -48px 330px hsl(1782, 100%, 50%), -49px 331px hsl(1787.4, 100%, 50%), -50px 332px hsl(1792.8, 100%, 50%), -51px 333px hsl(1798.2, 100%, 50%), -52px 334px hsl(1803.6, 100%, 50%), -53px 335px hsl(1809, 100%, 50%), -54px 336px hsl(1814.4, 100%, 50%), -55px 337px hsl(1819.8, 100%, 50%), -55px 338px hsl(1825.2, 100%, 50%), -56px 339px hsl(1830.6, 100%, 50%), -57px 340px hsl(1836, 100%, 50%), -57px 341px hsl(1841.4, 100%, 50%), -58px 342px hsl(1846.8, 100%, 50%), -58px 343px hsl(1852.2, 100%, 50%), -58px 344px hsl(1857.6, 100%, 50%), -59px 345px hsl(1863, 100%, 50%), -59px 346px hsl(1868.4, 100%, 50%), -59px 347px hsl(1873.8, 100%, 50%), -59px 348px hsl(1879.2, 100%, 50%), -59px 349px hsl(1884.6, 100%, 50%), -60px 350px hsl(1890, 100%, 50%), -59px 351px hsl(1895.4, 100%, 50%), -59px 352px hsl(1900.8, 100%, 50%), -59px 353px hsl(1906.2, 100%, 50%), -59px 354px hsl(1911.6, 100%, 50%), -59px 355px hsl(1917, 100%, 50%), -58px 356px hsl(1922.4, 100%, 50%), -58px 357px hsl(1927.8, 100%, 50%), -58px 358px hsl(1933.2, 100%, 50%), -57px 359px hsl(1938.6, 100%, 50%), -57px 360px hsl(1944, 100%, 50%), -56px 361px hsl(1949.4, 100%, 50%), -55px 362px hsl(1954.8, 100%, 50%), -55px 363px hsl(1960.2, 100%, 50%), -54px 364px hsl(1965.6, 100%, 50%), -53px 365px hsl(1971, 100%, 50%), -52px 366px hsl(1976.4, 100%, 50%), -51px 367px hsl(1981.8, 100%, 50%), -50px 368px hsl(1987.2, 100%, 50%), -49px 369px hsl(1992.6, 100%, 50%), -48px 370px hsl(1998, 100%, 50%), -47px 371px hsl(2003.4, 100%, 50%), -46px 372px hsl(2008.8, 100%, 50%), -45px 373px hsl(2014.2, 100%, 50%), -43px 374px hsl(2019.6, 100%, 50%), -42px 375px hsl(2025, 100%, 50%), -41px 376px hsl(2030.4, 100%, 50%), -39px 377px hsl(2035.8, 100%, 50%), -38px 378px hsl(2041.2, 100%, 50%), -36px 379px hsl(2046.6, 100%, 50%), -35px 380px hsl(2052, 100%, 50%), -33px 381px hsl(2057.4, 100%, 50%), -32px 382px hsl(2062.8, 100%, 50%), -30px 383px hsl(2068.2, 100%, 50%), -28px 384px hsl(2073.6, 100%, 50%), -27px 385px hsl(2079, 100%, 50%), -25px 386px hsl(2084.4, 100%, 50%), -23px 387px hsl(2089.8, 100%, 50%), -22px 388px hsl(2095.2, 100%, 50%), -20px 389px hsl(2100.6, 100%, 50%), -18px 390px hsl(2106, 100%, 50%), -16px 391px hsl(2111.4, 100%, 50%), -14px 392px hsl(2116.8, 100%, 50%), -13px 393px hsl(2122.2, 100%, 50%), -11px 394px hsl(2127.6, 100%, 50%), -9px 395px hsl(2133, 100%, 50%), -7px 396px hsl(2138.4, 100%, 50%), -5px 397px hsl(2143.8, 100%, 50%), -3px 398px hsl(2149.2, 100%, 50%), -1px 399px hsl(2154.6, 100%, 50%); font-size: 40px;";

console.log("%cExample %s", css, 'all code runs happy');
```

выведет в консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> И еще вопрос: можно ли в консоль вывести картинку, и если да, то как?

Не знаю как в других браузерах, но в Chrome, судя по **[коду из гитхаба](https://github.com/adriancooney/console.image/blob/master/console.image.js)**

Можно вставить картинку в консоль, также на основе CSS стилей:

```js
function getBox(width, height) {
  return {
    string: "+",
    style: "font-size: 1px; padding: " + Math.floor(height / 2) + "px " + Math.floor(width / 2) + "px; line-height: " + height + "px;"
  }
}


console.image = function(url, scale) {
  scale = scale || 1;
  var img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    var dim = getBox(this.width * scale, this.height * scale);
    console.log("%c" + dim.string, dim.style + "background: url(" + url + "); background-size: " + (this.width * scale) + "px " + (this.height * scale) + "px; color: transparent;");
  };

  img.src = url;
};

console.image('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uqn6.jpg');
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но второй вариант это уже наркомания, и причем создатели его курили наверное что-то жесткое. И еще вопрос: можно ли в консоль вывести картинку, и если да, то как?

Comment: @EugenEray если только написать свой метод на основе стилей.... но это не точно....Для Chrome дописал в ответ

Comment: А хотя нет, второй вариант это `Nyan Cat`

Comment: Вот, что надо было: http://i.imgur.com/dt02qBo.png    Спасибо за метод решения с картинкой.

Answer (score 2):

Для Вашего примера:

```
console.log ( '%c%s', 'color: red; font: 2rem/1 Tahoma;', 'Остановитесь!' );
```

---

Вывод в консоль сообщения осуществить можно с помощью `console.log()` и `console.dir()`.

[**ИСТОЧНИК**](http://css.yoksel.ru/funny-little-console/)

> Для того, чтобы задать оформление тексту, CSS-код нужно передать
>   отдельным параметром, причем первым параметром в этом случае должна
>   быть строка с указателями, вторым — строка с CSS, третьим — данные,
>   которые нужно вывести.

---

> `%s` — в виде строки; 
>  `%d` или `%i` — в виде числа; 
> `%f` — в виде
>   числа с плавающей точкой; 
> `%o` — в виде разворачиваемого DOM-элемента;
>   `%O` — в виде разворачиваемого JavaScript-объекта; 
>  `%c` — оформляет
>   вывод с соответствии с CSS, переданным дополнительным параметром.

---

**Пример 1:**

```
var str = 'Главный вопрос жизни вселенной и всего такого';
console.log ( '%c%s', 'color: green; font: 1.2rem/1 Tahoma;', str );
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Пример 2:**

```
var str = 'Главный вопрос жизни вселенной и всего такого';
var style = ['padding: 1rem;',
             'background: linear-gradient( gold, orangered);',
             'text-shadow: 0 2px orangered;',
             'font: 1.3rem/3 Georgia;',
             'color: white;'].join('');

console.log ( '%c%s', style, str );
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[**console API reference**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference)

---

**Поддержка:** Chrome, FF

Comment: А как `%o` можно юзануть?

Comment: @EugenEray, откройте статью, там все подробнее расписано. Для `%o` дом-элемента: 

`var h1Elem = document.querySelector('h1');

console.log ( '%o', h1Elem );`